# Python: Parse one string into multiple variables?

Tags: python, parsing

I am pretty sure that there is a function for this, but I been searching for a while, so decided to simply ask SO instead.

I am writing a Python script that parses and analyzes text messages from an input file. Each line looks like this:

> Oct 24, 2014, 19:20 - Lee White: Hello world!

or:

> Apr 4, 19:20 - Lee White: Hello world!

If the year in the datetime is not mentioned, it means that the message was sent in the **current year**.

What I want to do, is parse this string into multiple variables. Ideally, I am looking for a function that takes an input string, a format string, and a couple of variables to store the output in:

`foo(input, "MMM DD, YYYY, HH:MM - Sender: Text", &mon, &day, &year, &hour, &minutes, &sender, &text)`

Does such a thing exist in Python?

Comment: do you mean  parse the string and extracts those variables?

Comment: It should be fairly easy to write one if such a thing doesn't exist..... would you be happy with something that worked like: mon, day, year, hour, minutes, sender, text = foo(input)  ?

Comment: @justcompile: Yeah, that would work!

Comment: You have to do some regex or single string splitting (more likely splitting in this case), according my knowledge there does not exists such library function.

Answer (score 3):

This uses the remarkably useful `dateutil` library to make date parsing easier - you can `pip install python-dateutil` or `easy_install python-dateutil` it. Split the data on the `:` and the `-` to get message and sender, then process the date text to get a `datetime` object where you can access its various attributes to get the components required, eg:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

s = 'Apr 4, 19:20 - Lee White: Hello world!'
fst, _, msg = s.rpartition(': ')
date, _, name = fst.partition(' - ')
date = parse(date)
name, msg, date.year, date.month, date.day, date.hour, date.minute
# ('Lee White', 'Hello world!', 2015, 4, 4, 19, 20)
```

Comment: You pretty much stole my idea ;)

Comment: @Padraic I'm sure you'll find it in your heart to forgive me? :p

Comment: might take a few months  but I will get over it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Method strptime() may be used:

```
import time

strn = 'Apr 4, 19:20 - Lee White: Hello world!'

try:
    date = time.strptime(strn.split(' - ')[0],'%b %d, %Y, %H:%M')
    year = date.tm_year
except ValueError:
    date = time.strptime(strn.split(' - ')[0],'%b %d, %H:%M')
    year = time.asctime().split()[-1]

sender = strn.split('- ')[1].split(':')[0]
text = strn.split(': ')[1]

date.tm_mon, date.tm_mday, year, date.tm_hour, date.tm_min, sender, text
```