# Python regex parse middle string

Tags: python

I want to extract the strings in the middle of the following strings using Python

string = 'Components with opportunities:\n4150 UNDERCARRIAGE (2019-05-11)\n4151 TRACK ROLLER FRAME (2019-05-11)\n4157 TRACK ADJUSTER (2019-05-11)\n4164 SPROCKET ASSEMBLY (2019-03-18)\n4170 TRACK ASSEMBLY (2019-03-18)\n4172 TRACK SHOE (2019-03-18)'

such that the output is [UNDERCARRIAGE, TRACK ROLLER FRAME, TRACK ADJUSTER, SPROCKET ASSEMBLY, TRACK ASSEMBLY, TRACK SHOE]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Parse one string into multiple variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410123/python-parse-one-string-into-multiple-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to match everything from space upto opening parenthesis

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<= ).*?(?= \()', string)
['UNDERCARRIAGE', 'TRACK ROLLER FRAME', 'TRACK ADJUSTER', 'SPROCKET ASSEMBLY', 'TRACK ASSEMBLY', 'TRACK SHOE']
```